# Sharepoint 365: Get all items in a list (but says columns don't exist!)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've been beating my head over this problem and searching everywhere online to find an answer. I hope someone can help!

All I want to do is query a list in Sharepoint Online 365 and return all of the items in that list along with their column values.

The problem is that when I try to list the columns I want to include, which I know for a fact exist, I get an error saying they don't exist!

I can successfully retrieve "Title" and the item's ID. That's all. None of the custom columns.

Anyone know why?!?

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
/*Below line will make sure your JavaScript method will be called only after the SP.js file loaded at the client side*/
window.onload = QueryFollowUrl;
 
function QueryFollowUrl()
{
 //Gets the Client context of the Web
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 
 var web = context.get_web();
 
 //Change the List Name with yours
 this.list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Team Projects');
 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
 
 //Reframe the Caml query as per your requirements
 var query = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Details' /><FieldRef Name='Status' /></ViewFields></View>";
 camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
 listItems = this.list.getItems(camlQuery);
 context.load(list);  
 
 /*Now mention all the required filed internal name, since data from these fields only will be retrieved*/
 context.load(listItems, 'Include(Title, Details, Status)');
 //Makes asynchronous call to the Server, which will return the JSON objects
 context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.successFollow), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failedFollow));
 return false;
}
 
//you can get the Error details if your Execution fails using get_message() method
function failedFollow(sender, args)
{
    var errorMsg = args.get_message();
    document.getElementById('projects').innerHTML = errorMsg;
}

/*Upon successful execution, Success delegate method will be called and all the requested objects will the loaded with contents*/
function successFollow(sender, args)
{
 var ListEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();
 
 while (ListEnumerator.moveNext())
 {
   var collection = ListEnumerator.get_current();
 
   /*Using get_item method you can pass the Field Internal name mentioned earlier and get the data in that respective column, if you try to use any other column other than we mentioned earlier, it will throw you error.*/
 
   var itemTitle = collection.get_item('Title');
   document.getElementById('projects').innerHTML += itemTitle+' '+itemDetails+'<br>';
 
   //your code here
 
 }
}
</script>
```

```html
<h2>Current Projects (loaded using Javascript from the 'Team Projects' list)</h2>
<div id="projects"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can check using internal names of column?
go to list settings -> click on column name.
Then in the url you can find internal name of that column.

Comment: In the actual URL? It says "Field=e72u"....so the field is actually named "e72u"? Very odd.

Comment: I think you have created this field using 'Add Column' link  present in quick edit mode view of list. It creates field having some random characters ('e72u.. ' in your case) in name and later changes its display name.